# Calculating number of bookings per slot in booking system

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a booking system whereby customers are allowed to chose one from a list of available slots. The slots are known (09:00 - 17:00, every 15 minutes).

The length of the booking depends on the number of items to collect (calculated elsewhere), and will always round up to the nearest 15 minute slot.

What I'm trying to do is query the existing bookings and return a list of slots and the number of bookings in each slot. If a booking is 'in' a timeslot (e.g. a booking for 09:00 - 10:00 will be in 09:00, 09:15, 09:30m and 09:45), I just want to add 1 to each of those slot's counts.

I'll then join this result with a staff list to show how many staff are available (and therefore whether the slot is free), but this isn't part of this question.

Example return data:

```
TimeSlot | BookingsCount
------------------------
09:00    | 2
09:15    | 2
09:30    | 1
09:45    | 1
10:00    | 0
```

```sql
create table ScheduleTimes (t time);
insert into ScheduleTimes (t) values(('09:00'));
insert into ScheduleTimes (t) values(('09:15'));
insert into ScheduleTimes (t) values(('09:30'));
insert into ScheduleTimes (t) values(('09:45'));
insert into ScheduleTimes (t) values(('10:00'));
insert into ScheduleTimes (t) values(('10:15'));
insert into ScheduleTimes (t) values(('10:30'));
insert into ScheduleTimes (t) values(('10:45'));
insert into ScheduleTimes (t) values(('11:00'));
insert into ScheduleTimes (t) values(('11:15'));
insert into ScheduleTimes (t) values(('11:30'));
insert into ScheduleTimes (t) values(('11:45'));
insert into ScheduleTimes (t) values(('12:00'));
insert into ScheduleTimes (t) values(('12:15'));
insert into ScheduleTimes (t) values(('12:30'));

create table CollectionSchedule (ScheduleID int, CustomerID int, CollectionStart time, CollectionEnd time);
insert into CollectionSchedule values (1, 111, '09:00', '10:00');
insert into CollectionSchedule values (2, 222, '09:00', '09:30');
insert into CollectionSchedule values (3, 333, '09:30', '10:00');
insert into CollectionSchedule values (4, 444, '10:00', '10:15');
insert into CollectionSchedule values (5, 555, '10:00', '11:00');
insert into CollectionSchedule values (6, 666, '10:15', '10:45');
insert into CollectionSchedule values (7, 777, '10:45', '11:00');
```

[I've created an SQL Fiddle which is available here which has a demo schema set up.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/17b642) The schema isn't set in stone and can be changed if necessary, it's just what I've come up with so far.

Here's the demo schema:

Collection Schedule (list of appointments already made):

```
create table CollectionSchedule (ScheduleID int, CustomerID int, CollectionStart time, CollectionEnd time);
```

ScheduleTimes (A list of available time slots);

```
create table ScheduleTimes (t time);
```

Here's my latest query attempt:

```
select 
    st.t,
    SUM(sq1.intimeframe) as BookingsCount
from
    ScheduleTimes st
    left join (
        select 
            st.t as Slot,
            case when (st.t <= cs.CollectionStart and st.t < cs.CollectionEnd) then 1 else 0 end as intimeframe 
        from CollectionSchedule cs, @ScheduleTimes st
    ) sq1 on st.t = sq1.Slot
group by st.t
```

but this returns incorrect values for the number of bookings in each slot because it counts entries multiple times, and is I'm clearly going down the wrong path and am a bit lost. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this return the appropriate values?

```
SELECT Agg.T, COUNT(*) 
FROM(SELECT s.T FROM CollectionSchedule as c
INNER JOIN ScheduleTimes as s 
ON s.T >= c.CollectionStart AND s.T < c.CollectionEnd) as Agg
GROUP BY Agg.T;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/293ee/1)

Comment: My friend, you've done it. Thanks for being able to decipher the dribbling mess of a question, and for teaching me new things. Time to start some learning about cross joins. Thanks again.

Comment: That's not strictly a `CROSS JOIN`. Change it to an `INNER` and make the `WHERE` clause the `ON` clause.

Comment: @gvee Makes sense. I'll edit the answer in case someone in the future has the same type of question

Answer (score 0):

Just a left join on interval intersection

```
select 
    st.t,
    count(cs.ScheduleID) n
from
    ScheduleTimes st
    left join CollectionSchedule cs on cs.CollectionStart < dateadd(minute, 15, st.t) and  st.t < cs.CollectionEnd
group by st.t
```